# SWF Upload: Returning errors

Tags: php, file-upload, http-headers, swfupload

I've been messing around with SWF Upload, and I really like it. I was able to apply it very easily to my file upload class with very little issue. The problem I am having, however, is that I need to be able to send back errors to the uploader so a user knows if their file actually wasn't completely uploaded due to issues such as it being too large, or of the wrong format, ect. I read through the PHP example script that the writers of SWF Upload provide, but I cannot figure out how to pass back the errors to it. This is there error handling function:

```
/* Handles the error output.  This function was written for SWFUpload for Flash Player 8 which
cannot return data to the server, so it just returns a 500 error. For Flash Player 9 you will
want to change this to return the server data you want to indicate an error and then use SWFUpload's
uploadSuccess to check the server_data for your error indicator. */

function HandleError($message) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $message;
}
```

So the uploadSuccess function is expecting a response from the server. How would I go about encoding and sending that said response using "header()"?

If I use this:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 Uploaded File was Successful");
```

SWF Upload returns success, but that message does not come through to the uploadSuccess function.

Comment: HttpResponse::setCache(true);
HttpResponse::status(200);
HttpResponse::setContentType('text/html');
HttpResponse::setData('this is the error text');
HttpResponse::send();
If I try something like this, SWF Upload returns a 500 error, but the file is still uploaded.

Comment: Just `echo` your message after the header call it seems (don't have your 'SWF uploader' handy, but I gather that at least is what the error function does).

Comment: I've figured it out. I was using a handler script they also provide on their website, and I found the uploadSuccess handler function in it. It was just outputting "Complete." By passing it the serverData variable, it works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to display an error message from the server. Based on the comments above, I was able to get this to work by updating the uploadSuccess() function in handlers.js to:

```
if (serverData != null && serverData != "ok"){
  progress.setError();
  progress.setStatus(serverData);
} else {
  progress.setStatus("Complete.");
}
```

Meaning, if the response is anything other than "ok" it will be displayed as an error. This feels pretty hacky. I'd much rather be able to send a non-200 response from the server and have it show the error message from that, but as far I can tell that's not possible. Also, the way I've got it set up wouldn't work for custom messages that aren't errors.